# 401: Authentication Fail with generated API token

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, jwt

I have this Javascript code that generates a token to access the Apple Store api. But when I try to use the token I get "401: Unauthorized access" code. I'm not sure if the code I'm using correct or maybe it might be an issue with the id and key I'm using.

```
console.log(" appStoreConnectAPIFromNode.js running ‍")

const fs   = require('fs');
const jwt  = require('jsonwebtoken'); // npm i jsonwebtoken
// You get privateKey, apiKeyId and issuerId from your Apple App Store Connect account
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync("./AuthKey-12345678.p8") // this is the file you can only download once and should treat like a real, very precious key.
const apiKeyId = "12345678"
const issuerId = "issuerId"
let now = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000); // Notice the /1000 
let nowPlus20 = now + 1199 // 1200 === 20 minutes

let payload = {
    "iss": issuerId,
    "exp": nowPlus20,
    "aud": "appstoreconnect-v1"
}

let signOptions = {
    "algorithm": "ES256", // you must use this algorithm, not jsonwebtoken's default
    header : {
        "alg": "ES256",
        "kid": apiKeyId,
        "typ": "JWT"
    }
};

let token = jwt.sign(payload, privateKey, signOptions);
console.log('@token: ', token);

fs.writeFile('Output.txt', token, (err) => { 
      
    // In case of a error throw err. 
    if (err) throw err; 
})

// Congrats! the token printed can now be tested with the curl command below
// curl -v https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/apps --Header "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR TOKEN>"
// (no '<>' in the curl command)
```

Comment: Q: Have you looked at this in Chrome Dev tools (or equivalent)?  What are the values of nowPlus20, payload and signOptions before you send?  Have you inspected the full HTTP response - is Apple sending you any additional info?  Q: How exactly are you trying to connect? Is jwt,sign() making a network call?  Or is the JS just writing to a text file (for later use)?

Comment: @paulsm4 The jwt is outputting the token to a txt file. I then copy and past token for the txt file to run this command ***curl -v https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/apps --Header "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR TOKEN>"***. The value of nowPlus20 should be "1528408800"

Comment: *The value of nowPlus20 should be "1528408800"* - is that just an example or an actual value? Because that would be 06/07/2018 @ 10:00pm (UTC)

Comment: The "1528408800" number is just an example not the actual value that would be generated